# Google Oauth Data Storage Period

Tags: oauth, storage, google-oauth, policy, user-data

How long can a developer store permission-based user data (email, contacts)? I'm unable to find specific documentation on this.

Comment: I don't think there are specific rules for this, since Google has no way of controlling what the developers are storing or not. I guess the recommendation is to make it clear for the users what you are saving and giving them options to opt-out, delete the data, etc. This obviously depends on your application.